# WordPress upload media using Backbone JS Client

Tags: javascript, wordpress, backbone.js, wordpress-rest-api

How to upload a media file using the [WordPress Backbone JS Client](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/backbone-javascript-client/)?

I can create a new post of type media, but how to attach an actual file to it?

```
// Create a new media
var media = new wp.api.models.Media( { title: 'This is a demo file' } );
media.save();
```

Answer (score 0):

### Using WP Media Library

**Step 1** - Enable WP Media Library on pages you are going to use it

In functions.php or a template file

```
wp_enqueue_media();
```

**Step 2** - Open the Media Library

```
var image = wp.media({
    title: 'Upload Image',
    type: 'image',
    multiple: false,
    button: {
        text: 'Done'
    }
}).open()
```

**Step 3** - Get the attachment ID

```
image.on('select', function(e){
    var uploaded_image = image.state().get('selection').first();
    var image_id = uploaded_image.toJSON().id;
    $('input#image-id').val(image_id);
});
```

**Step 4** - Set attachment to a post as a featured image (for example)

```
var image_id = parseInt($('input#image-id').val());

var post = new wp.api.models.Post( {
    title: "Post with an attachment",
    featured_media: image_id
} );

post.save();
```